# CPU time counting for multiple snippets in a python program

Tags: python, time, cpu-usage

I am writing code to count CPU time for a program. The related code is like this:

```
   with open(script_path, "r") as src:
        scr_contents = src.read()

   proc = subprocess.run(["python", script_path], capture_output = True)

   cup_time = time.process_time()
```

This script gives me the CPU time for running the whole program of scr_contents.

Now, suppose I have many snippets in this program and I want to get the CPU time for each snippets, what method or function available for this purpose of CPU time counting?

Comment: You should understand that it also takes time for a separate Python process to start up and shut down again for each script that you test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you profile a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)